# How to print é as '%C3%A9' in Python 2.7

Tags: python, encoding, uri

I want to convert '**é**' to **%C3%A9** for URI request.

My code is like this:

```
import urllib 
actor = "Bonnie Erbé"
```

I know that I can manually covert it by

```
print urllib.quote(u"Bonnie Erbé".encode("utf-8")).
```

However, I want to use the variable **actor**.

When I try

```
print urllib.quote(actor)
```

It prints `'Bonnie%20Erb%E9'` not `'Bonnie%20Erb%C3%A9'`.

Thank you.

Comment: That `encode` method you're using works on string values in variables like `actor` just as well as it does on string values in literals like `u"Bonnie Erbé".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your program look like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import urllib
actor = u"Bonnie Erbé"

print urllib.quote(u"Bonnie Erbé".encode("utf-8"))

print urllib.quote(actor.encode('utf-8'))
```

Notice:

1) An `encoding: utf-8` line that says you'll have non-ASCII characters in your text file.

2) Assigning a unicode string, not a plain string, to the `actor` variable.

3) Encoding `actor` just the same as you encoded the literal string.

Comment: bah you beat me ... and you even explained what was happening +1 :P

Comment: But surely he doesn't have the literal assignment that I fixed in 2. Surely he's reading the actor's name from a file or a website or a user-interface element. Somebody will have to explain to OP about Unicode sandwiches and http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html. That won't be me, I have to run. @JoranBeasley -- feel free to update your answer, give a good explanation of encoding/decoding, and steal anything you want from my answer.

Comment: I am reading actor list from DB. Do we have any way to add "u"? So, my next question will be how to make "Bonnie Erbé" to u"Bonnie Erbé" not manually.

Comment: Maybe not unicode("Bonnie Erbé") because it returns error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: you could try `"Bonnie Erbé".decode("latin1")` its weird that you get 0xc3 ... it should be 0x83 ... which makes me think its perhaps encoded differently ... `print repr("Bonnie Erbé")` ...amybe its already utf8 encoded on your system ... try `decode("utf8")` ... although if you are just going to reencode it thats a little pointless

Comment: Thank you. The actor list has many other languages than latin, but I think that this will work at least for English.

Comment: @AydenKim - How are you reading the data from database? The general strategy is to convert any byte-oriented representation to Unicode immediately upon reading it, keep everything in Unicode inside the program, and convert back to byte representation only when writing it out. The link that I posted really is helpful.

Comment: @Rob - I cannot open the link. Can you try it?

Comment: @AydenKim If you can't open http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html , try googling "Ned Batchelder: Pragmatic Unicode". Ned's presentation should be at or near the top.